# Compartir datos globales

Tags: php

Me encuentro con la necesidad de compartir valores entre scripts, la mayoría de ellos, se van llamando, con lo que podría prever alguna solución, aunque me gustaría que fuera mas "libre", pero hay un caso de un proceso que se llama por CRON y que puede actuar o no, según un valor que proporcionan los scripts que están corriendo. La primera solución que se me ocurre, es a través de disco...pero ¿hay alguna otra solución?¿Puedo definir variables con scope "total"?

EDICION:En vista de la dificultad, me contesto a mi mismo. Utilizo fichero; me he creado este modulo

```
class VariablesGlobales
{
    private static $variable=[];
    const FIC_VAR = "FicheroVariablesGlobales.tmp";
    const FIC_PATH = _DIR_;

    public static function setVariable($nombre,$valor){
        self::leerDisco();
        self::$variable[$nombre]=$valor;
        self::grabarDisco();
    }

    public static function getVariable($nombre){
        self::leerDisco();
        if (array_key_exists($nombre,self::$variable)){
            return self::$variable[$nombre];
        } else {
            return null;
        }       
    }

    public static function getAll() {
        self::leerDisco();
        return self::$variable;
    }

    public static function clearAll(){
        self::$variable=[];
        self::grabarDisco();
    }

    public static function unsetVariable($nombre){
        self::leerDisco();
        if (array_key_exists($nombre,self::$variable)){
           unset(self::$variable[$nombre]);
           self::grabarDisco();
        } 
    }
    private static function leerDisco(){
        $fiche=FIC_PATH . FIC_VAR;
        if (is_file($fiche))
            self::$variable=json_decode(file_get_content($fiche),true);
        else {
            self::$variable=[];
        }
    }
    private static function grabarDisco(){
        $fiche=FIC_PATH . FIC_VAR;
        file_put_contents( $fiche,json_encode(self::$array));
    }


}
```

luego, solo tengo que llamarlo

```
VariablesGlobales::setVariable('ficheroCargado', 1);
```

o

```
 VariablesGlobales::getVariable('usbConectado')
```

Comment: No entiendo bien la pregunta porque el proceso php disparado por cron no tiene visibilidad sobre otros procesos concurrentes en php que puedan estar corriendo, por ejemplo, ejecuciones de usuarios visitando el sitio.

Comment: Ese es un problema, por eso preguntaba si hay alguna forma de definir variables visibles por cualquier programa . No queria acudir a disco, porque no deseo persistencia, y si lo dejo en disco, necesitare codigo auxiliar para borrarlo.

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: Tene en cuenta que si cada proceso corre por separado, y el lenguaje no ofrece una forma de compartir recursos (lo que pasa en la mayoria de ellos) no vas a poder. O tenes alguna especie de cola a donde te puedas conectar al iniciar tu programa.. o vas a tener que compartirlos con archivos.

Comment: Todo el desarrollo se hace en PHP,...pero veo que la solucion pasa por utilizar fichero

Comment: La cuestión es persistir la información. Eso la forma más segura de hacerlo, en vez de declarar variables que se pretendan super super super globales, es con herramientas que existen de toda la vida para persistir datos (ficheros, bases de datos), Incluso, ya que hablas de cron, una posibilidad sería salirte del entorno PHP y trabajarlo todo a nivel del sistema operativo (lo lanzo sólo como idea, según el contexto, podría ser una opción interesante).